# Lapply to filter values of one list using another list as a criteria

Tags: r

Suppose you have one list of data frames called list1 and another list of data frames called list2.

Both lists have data about the same individuals, and you have a unique id to identify them. I would like to filter the second list to have only data about those individuals that are on the first list.

I was thinking of something on these lines:

```
list1 %>% lapply(distinct, ID) -> id1
list2 %>% lapply(filter, ID %in% id1) -> list2
```

So, I would like to iterate the filter function matching element-by-element in both lists, like,

```
filter(list2[[1]], ID %in% id1[[1]])
```

and so on.

However, this approach does not work. I believe it is because the criteria is a list. Using the following for loop I was able to obtain the desired result:

```
for (i in seq(list2)) {
  list2[[i]] %>%
      filter(ID %in% id1[[i]][,1]) -> list2[[i]]
```

Is there a way to do what I describe using lapply()?

Comment: Please include sample data to make a reproducible problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Also, how long are both lists? Does `df1` in `list2` contain the filters for `df1` in `list1`, and so on?

Comment: Does it have to using base R?

Comment: Not necessarily. I would like to avoid a loop, that's all.

Comment: The lists are of the same size. Each component of each list have the same ID, i.e, an ID = 1 in list1 will represent the same object in list2.